# Google apps script - format borders based on cells not matching to build a read friendly report

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to put a border (for ease of reading) into a report. I found some code that was close and tried adjusting it, but I'm obviously not understanding arrays and ranges well enough to follow what is happening.  [Google Sheet I am working with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1naDiKVEm_81dTTCo5YcduLopHiHtOzRHv5_t8svLGFo/edit?usp=sharing).  I basically want a border to show when a student and their group of data changes (A through H). Because a student's 'Health Visits', 'Absences', '% Present', and    'Missing work' rolls up to one value per student; but a student takes more than one course and receives a score for each course, I made the font white (using conditional formatting based on values in column K) so it doesn't show over and over if is more than one group of data per student. I use VLOOKUPs to pull in the data I need; and then a concatenate formula to pull the grouped data together (ignoring classes and scores) in column K. I want to read through column K and when the value changes (or does not match), I want to add a border above that line to show a break between students. There may be a better/easier way to do this - but it's what I've come up with so far.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Here are two screen shots - one of what the report looks like without borders and one with what I'd like it to look like with borders:
[image]
[image]
And this is the code I am working with.  I added to the comments where I have a lack of understanding:

```
function applyBorders() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report");

    // get key variables
    var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var LastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

    //erase any current formatting 
    var ClearRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, LastRow, LastColumn).setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false); // clear all formatting

    // get the data
    var data = sheet.getRange(2, 12, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //This I don't understand. I want it to be column K so
                                                                                             // so it can read through and find the dupes.

    // setup new array  
    var ListofIdentifiers = new Array();  //I don't understand what this does . . . just hold a space for the new array values?

    // Loop through the Identifying Column (Column K?)
    for (var i in data) {
        var row = data[i][1].toString(); //Is this converting to a string because it is a formula? Should I cut and paste special to make it values vs. a formula?


        // search for Identifiers that don't match
        if (ListofIdentifiers.indexOf(row) !=-1) { // if value is not =-1, then the variable is not unique

            // underline the previous row -- not understanding exactly what the range below is looking at?
            var range = sheet.getRange((+i + 1), 9, 1, 1).setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false, "blue", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); // format if true

            // continue to build array
            ListofIdentifiers.push(row);
        }

    }
    // underline the last row  - this works!
    var range = sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1, 1, 10).setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "blue", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); // format if true
    // Logger.log(ListofFruits);// DEBUG
}
```

[image]

Comment: Need access to Sheets. Kindly share the Sheet or attach screenshot of sheet and the desired output.

Comment: I apologize as I thought I did. Does the link not work? I will post more. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your code, modified some parts and added some comments.

**Try this:**

```
function applyBorders() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
    
    var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var LastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var StartRow = 2;
    var StartCol = 11;
    
    //erase any current formatting 
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, LastRow, LastColumn).setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false); // clear all formatting
    
    // get the data from column K
    var range = sheet.getRange(StartRow, StartCol, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
    var data = range.getValues();
    //The data we collect are rows of data, each row represent sub array in 2d array.
    //merge 2d array into 1d
    var merged = [].concat.apply([], data);
    //loop through each element of merged array.
    for( var i in merged){
      var id = merged[i];
      var id_prev = merged[parseInt(i)-1];
      
      //check if the current id is not equal to the previous id
      //added id_prev != undefined to prevent true if i == 0
      if(id != id_prev && id_prev != undefined){
        //set top border
        var borderRange = sheet.getRange((StartRow + parseInt(i)), 1, 1, 10);
        borderRange.setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false, "blue", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);        
      }
    }
    sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1, 1, 10).setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, "blue", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);
}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Reference:**

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you Nikko! I appreciate the comments and the reference to better help me understand ranges, etc.. On this line:  'var merged = [].concat.apply([], data);' - does that like build a placeholder? And then when it loops through it assigns the value it picks up? I'm not sure I'm asking that right, and I don't quite understand that piece and how the 'i' got involved. I think I've only seen it initialized by using an the equal sign. 'var i in merged' - is that a type/form of initialization?

Comment: The output of `var data = range.getValues();`  is `[[1][1][1][2][2]....]`. What `merged` does is it will convert those 2d array into 1d, [1,1,1,2,2,...].

Comment: Also, array have index, index is referring to the position of the element. To access the content of the array, you have to specify the position of the element. Example: I have array `merged = [1,2,3,4]`. if I want to access the 3rd element of the array I will write it like this `merged[2]` (array index starts at 0), which is equal to `3`. `var i` is just a placeholder for the index. It will iterates until it reach the size of the array. See [Javascript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: That helps, thank you! The only issue I'm having right now is that last line of code put in to put a bottom border on the last line. What it's doing is removing if there is a top line on it, which needs to be there if the records don't match. I thought an if statement may work but I keep getting errors. How would you handle it?

Comment: @Karen - I rollback the last line to use null instead of false. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Thank you, however I'm getting an error, which I pasted above. How does it throw an error on line 5, when it hasn't even gotten to line 32 where it sets the value to null? Will I EVER get this? :)

Comment: I got it Nikko!  After researching the error, I found that I was referencing the wrong sheet.  I had changed things up a bit and didn't realize it. My bad!  It looks great and thank you so much for all your help with this!!!!